# How do I import an HTML email template to Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird

This is probably easy, but I can't figure it out. I've downloaded an HTML email template from http://www.campaignmonitor.com/templates/ which seems to just be an HTML file + images.

How do I use this with Thunderbird to send it as an HTML email?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the instructions below to insert your HTML template:

> When you compose an HTML message, you
>   can insert HTML tags or edit existing
>   HTML tags in the message:
>
> 1. Optionally, to edit existing HTML tags, select part of the message,
>      or select the entire message (for
>      example, by pressing Ctrl+A or by
>      choosing Edit -> Select All).
> 2. Choose: Insert -> HTML...
> 3. Edit the HTML code as desired.
> 4. Press Insert.
>
> See below for extensions that provide
>   other ways to edit HTML tags.
>
> Note:  Some people who receive your
>   message might not see the effect of
>   any changes that you make to HTML
>   tags. For example, Thunderbird users
>   might choose to display messages as
>   plain text or as simple HTML, and
>   webmail clients might change your HTML
>   in various ways.

**PLEASE NOTE:**

When you do this just make sure that you have all your images hosted somewhere. (webserver, image hosting server. etc.) Sure the images may be visible while on your computer but when they are on someone else that will not be the case. They will see broken image placeholders.

Reference: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Edit_HTML_source

Comment: Seems that as of newer Thunderbird versions, the *Insert » HTML* option is no longer available.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this isn't just a SpamRoll, have you looked at their [instructions](http://help.campaignmonitor.com/topic.aspx?t=115)?  Where did you get stuck?